How to word break text with Pango
I would like to word break text, to separate text into distinct words or tokens. Somewhere online recommended using Pango. I would prefer a pangomm gtkmm solution but I would settle for a Pango GTK solution.
I find no examples online about how to word break text with Pango or pangomm. I find information about Pango.break, pangomm::Pango::Analysis, and pangomm::Pango::Item, but I don't know how to use them to word break text.

Each language has different libraries or functions that serve to separate strings, in most cases using regular expressions, it doesn't seem to me that pango has anything to do with what you want to do.
